# Diff command to return "Only In" differences between directories

Tags: unix, diff

I'm using the diff command to compare two Wordpress directories (one that was recently attacked by a vulnerability, and the other that is the plain copy). In the mist of my diff commands, I have tons of differs, but few "Only in"

For example:

```
Files public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php and public_html 2/wp-includes/widgets.php differ
Files public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php and public_html 2/wp-includes/wp-db.php differ
Files public_html/wp-includes/wp-diff.php and public_html 2/wp-includes/wp-diff.php differ
Files public_html/wp-login.php and public_html 2/wp-login.php differ
Only in public_html 2/: wp-options.php
Files public_html/wp-signup.php and public_html 2/wp-signup.php differ
```

I care about the 'Only in' outputs. What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the output to a grep-like command to filter it. Given directories a/ and b/:

```
diff -qr a/ b/ | fgrep 'Only in'
```

Or, if you wish to skip case sensitivity, you can try:

```
diff -qr a/ b/ | fgrep -i 'Only in'
```

Comment: Just tried $ diff -qr public_html/ public_html\ 2/ | fgrep 'Only In' , no results are outputted

Comment: Never mind, I solved it. The 'Only in' is case sensitive and I accidentally had a capital i for in

Comment: you could do fgrep -i for case insensitive